# How to remove the first column (index) from data table in R Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, dt

I am wondering if there is a way to remove the index column (1st column) from the data table in Shiny.

For example, column of (1, 2, 3) before **Name** column as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Test"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
)

body <- dashboardBody(
            box(title = "Test", width = 7, status = "warning", DT::dataTableOutput("df"))
)

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$df = DT::renderDataTable(df, options = list(
    autoWidth = TRUE,
    columnDefs = list(list(width = '10px', targets = c(1,3)))))
    }

# Shiny dashboard
shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just index it out when you render it, `DT::renderDataTable(df[-1], ...)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is some excellent documentation of the package available at https://rstudio.github.io/DT/ I would highly recommend reading through.

At any rate, use the `rownames = FALSE` argument provided by the `DT` package as follows:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

df <- mtcars

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Test"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  box(title = "Test", width = 7, status = "warning", DT::dataTableOutput("df"))
)

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$df = DT::renderDataTable(df, rownames = FALSE,
                                  options = list(
                                    autoWidth = TRUE,
                                    columnDefs = list(list(width = '10px', targets = c(1,3)))))
}

# Shiny dashboard
shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```